# Linking two sentences with a comma?

Tags: commas, compound-sentences

I'm wondering if the following sentence is correct?

> Please let me know your thoughts on these issues, I welcome your feedback.

Answer (score 6):

It's called a *[comma splice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comma%20splice)*:-

> the unjustified use of a comma between coordinate main clauses not
>   connected by a conjunction (as in “nobody goes there anymore, it's
>   boring”)

or a *[comma fault](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/comma%20fault)*:-

> the use of a comma, rather than a semicolon, colon, or period, to
>   separate related main clauses in the absence of a coordinating
>   conjunction: often considered to be incorrect or undesirable,
>   especially in formal writing.

As these sources mention, it is "often considered incorrect or undesirable".

Try reading the sentence aloud with a comma and with a full stop. The difference will be audible and the comma splice will make it sound gabbled.

Comment: Had to look [gabbled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gabbled) up

Comment: I would have thought that *to gabble* is not uncommon in BrE?

Comment: Is there any way to distinguish between sentences in which a comma splice is acceptable and those in which it isn't? In this cheesy sentence, I would hesitate to replace the comma even with a semicolon: *The years became months, the months became days.* Are the two clauses somehow more inseparable than in OP's sentence?

Comment: @KaiserOctavius See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Chapter 20, Section 3.2.3 "Asyndetic combinations of main clauses".